# How can I call a json object array, which is in one function, into another function?

Tags: jquery, json

This is puzzling me.  How can I make the following json function...

```
$.mfjson = function() {
var mjson = { LinkToDesktopSite : [    
{"section":"aboutus","name":"DemoA","mobile":"demoa.htm","desktop":"/desktop/demoa.aspx"},
{"section":"google","name":"DemoB","mobile":"demob.htm","desktop":"http://www.google.com"}
 ]};
}
```

...communicate with my .each method that is in another function...

```
 $.loopjson = function() {
 $.each(mfjson().mjson.LinkToDesktopSite, function(key,value) {
   var external = "www.";   
   if((value['mobile'] == url)) { 
    if((value['desktop'].indexOf(external) == -1)) {
     $('.readmore').attr("href","https://www.mysite.org"+value['desktop']);
     }else{
       $('.readmore').attr("href",value['desktop']);
     }
   }
 });
}
```

Getting firebug console errors saying that .loopjson has no clue what mfjson is.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  Added the "return mjson to the first function and $.mfjson().LinkToDesktopSite to the additional function...

```
$.mfjson = function() {
var mjson = { LinkToDesktopSite : [    
{"section":"aboutus","name":"DemoA","mobile":"demoa.htm","desktop":"/desktop/demoa.aspx"},
{"section":"google","name":"DemoB","mobile":"demob.htm","desktop":"http://www.google.com"}
]};
return mjson;
}

$.loopjson = function() {
 $.each($.mfjson().LinkToDesktopSite, function(key,value) {
 var external = "www.";   
 if((value['mobile'] == url)) { 
 if((value['desktop'].indexOf(external) == -1)) {
 $('.readmore').attr("href","https://www.mysite.org"+value['desktop']);
 }else{
   $('.readmore').attr("href",value['desktop']);
  }
 }
});
}
```